# In DBeaver, how do you export the results of multiple queries to different files?

Tags: dbeaver

In DBeaver, you can select more than one SELECT statement and export the results of those statements to a CSV file. Is it possible to export the results to different CSV files without exporting them one at a time? In the confirmation page of the export dialog there's a list of all the exports that are about to be performed. One of the columns in the list is "Target" and it has the same filename listed for each query. Is there a way to change the filenames? On the previous export dialog page there's a filename pattern but no indication of a variable to use to differentiate the queries to be exports.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Dean

Answer (score 1):

This is an OLD thread.

in the current version:

Select Queries >
Execute > Export from query

A wizard will guide you through.

Answer (score 0):

A change request that addressed this issue was entered on 12/4/2019:

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/7370

> New variable ${index} was introduced.
>   Also you can configure timestamp pattern and use milliseconds there (e.g. HHmmssSSS)